# CORS error when update the data in Angular 9

Tags: angular, cors, angular9

I have no problem when using the header something as below but face the CORS error when using the put method. After several try, I manually hard code the body into it but still facing the cors error when clicking the submit button to trigger this service in UI.

The error message show me something like this: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url path...]. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

```
  updateData(dataObj: GroupData,id: number ): Observable<any> {

     let httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
       })
       , withCredentials: true
     };
    
    const url= this.base+ 'Group/'+ id;

    var body = dataObj
    let bodynew = '{"ID":23425,"Name": "Test","Info": "Test Data"}';

    return this.http.put<GroupData>(url,  bodynew, httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the request url exists? Sometimes I get CORS issues when the backend returns client errors because I am posting to a not existing url.

Answer (score 0):

It must be handled from your backend. Your backend should allow your origin(your frontend host url) to receive http requests.

Comment: Currently in my white list have those in backend "localhost:4200", "localhost","My local pc name"

Comment: how did you whitelist them in your backend?

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

Add ***Cross Origin*** as *true* in the Http Options. If this is not resolving your issue then you need change some origin related changes in the Server side.

```
...
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
         'Cross-Origin': true
  })
...
```